# how to compare (domain) the value of a many2many field by itself?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to compare the value of a field many2many `line_mission` by the value entered by the user, just to check if an employee is already in a time interval, I tried this code but it doesn't work not :

**My field Many2many :**

```
line_mission = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Employés', help="Employee sent on mission", 
                            copy=True, auto_join=True,readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
```

**And my function to check if an employee is between `mission_start_date` and `mission_end_date` :**

```
    @api.multi
    @api.constrains('mission_start_date', 'mission_end_date')
    @api.depends('line_mission.name')
    def _check_date(self):
        for mission in self:    
            employee = self.env['hr.employee'].search_count([('name', '=', self.id)])
            domain = [
                ('mission_start_date', '<=', mission.mission_end_date),
                ('mission_end_date', '>=', mission.mission_start_date),
                ('id', '!=', mission.id),
                ('state', 'not in', ['end_mission']),
            ]
            nmissions = self.search_count(domain)
            if employee in mission.line_mission.name and nmissions:
                raise UserError(_('Vous ne pouvez pas avoir 2 missions qui se chevauchent le même jour!'))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your function.

1. You don't need to use `api.depends` because `api.constrains` is already triggering the function.
2. You should add `line_mission` in your `api.constrains`, because the constraint should be checked if the employee many2many field is changed.
3. Try to stick to the Odoo guidelines and rename/refactor your many2many field from `line_mission` to `employee_ids` or `employee_on_mission_ids`.
4. Don't use `search_count` if you need to use a record(set) later on. Meant is the first line in the foreach loop.
5. Use record(set)s in comparisons, for example in your `if`.

```py
@api.multi
@api.constrains('mission_start_date', 'mission_end_date', 'line_mission')
def _check_date(self):
    for mission in self:
        # the following search is really weird
        # do you always find exactly one?
        # do you really want to search on `name` with `ìd`?
        employee = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('name', '=', self.id)])
        domain = [
            ('mission_start_date', '<=', mission.mission_end_date),
            ('mission_end_date', '>=', mission.mission_start_date),
            ('id', '!=', mission.id),
            ('state', 'not in', ['end_mission']),
        ]
        nmissions = self.search_count(domain)
        # check if record is in recordset
        if employee in mission.line_mission and nmissions:
            raise UserError(_('Vous ne pouvez pas avoir 2 missions qui se chevauchent le même jour!'))
```

Comment: I tried your code it doesn't work, there's always overlap between employees in a time interval

Comment: The problem probably lies in the employee search, which i didn't understand. That's why i put the comment above it. I just wanted to hint you some mistakes. I didn't even know on what model this constraint is implemented.